# Bitbake - building a recipe for native target

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

**C**an we download bitbake separatly from poky distribution to build a recipe for the host machine as a target ?

**I**f the answer is yes, it would be very appreciated to explain the steps.

**A**lso, will the recipe be enough for the build, or it is mandatory to create a layer with the recipe included in it ?

Comment: Did you read [bitbake manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html)?

Comment: Yes I did, as far as I am concerned there is no plenty information about that specific point.

Comment: Yes, that's possible to build a native recipe. You could find some examples in existing layers. Your custom recipe must be created in a layer, custom or not

Comment: Do I need to have the poky distribution to use bitbake ? I'm wondering if It's possible to juste have bitbake installed, without poky, in a my host machine to build native recipes.